# How to extract 100 numbers at a time from a text file?

Tags: bash

I am absolutely new to bash scripting but I need to perform some task with it. I have a file with just one column of numbers (6250000). I need to extract 100 at a time, put them  into a new file and submit each 100 to another program. I think this should be some kind of a loop going through my file each 100 numbers and submitting them to the program.

Let's say my numbers in the file would look like this.

```
1.6435
-1.2903
1.1782
-0.7192
-0.4098
-1.7354
-0.4194
 0.2427
 0.2852
```

I need to feed each of those 62500 output files to a program which has a parameter file. I was doing something like this:

```
lossopt()
{
cat<<END>temp.par
Parameters for LOSSOPT
***********************

START OF PARAMETERS:
lossin.out                            \Input file with distribution
1                                       \column number
lossopt.out                             \Output file
-3.0 3.0   0.01                      \xmin, xmax, xinc
-3.0 1
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
3.0 0.12

END
}
for i in {1..62500}
do
sed -n 1,100p ./rearnum.out > ./lossin.out
echo temp.par | ./lossopt >> lossopt.out
rm lossin.out
cut -d " " -f 101- rearnum.out > rearnum.out
done
```

rearnum is my big initial file

Comment: If you're _new to bash scripting_ but _need to perform some task with it_, maybe invest your time in learning Python/Perl? Bash is (more than) fine for one liners (e.g., a list of commands where the stdout of one is connected by pipe to the stdin on the next one) but for any serious challenges, bash will make you go through hoops not required by a scripting language. Now, since you can execute a script by putting a shebang (`#!`) at the top, or calling it directly from the bash line  (e.g. `$ python -c "print 'hello world'"`), there's no need to invest too much time in bash studies.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to split it into files containing 100 lines each, I'd use `split -l 100 <source>` which will create a lot of files named like `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, ... each of which contain at most 100 lines of the source file (the last file may contain fewer).  If you want the names to start with something other than `x` you can give the prefix those names should use as the last argument to `split` as in `split -l 100 <source> OUT` which will now give files like `OUTaa`, `OUTab`, ...

Then you can loop over those files and process them however you like.  If you need to run a script with them you could do something like

```
for file in OUT*; do
    <other_script> "$file"
done
```

Comment: I need to feed each of those 62500 output files to a program which has a parameter file. I was doing something like this:

Comment: lossopt()
{
cat<<END>temp.par
                      Parameters for LOSSOPT
                      ***********************
 
START OF PARAMETERS:
lossin.out                            \Input file with distribution
1                                       \column number
lossopt.out                             \Output file
-3.0 3.0   0.01                      \xmin, xmax, xinc
-3.0 1
 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
 3.0 0.12
 
END
}
for i in {1..62500}
do
sed -n 1,100p ./rearnum.out > ./lossin.out
echo temp.par | ./lossopt >> lossopt.out
rm lossin.out
cut -d " " -f 101- rearnum.out > rearnum.out
done

Comment: I'm afraid it's not really clear to me what you want the output files to look like.  Do you want them all to have the header you're `cat`ing there, followed by 100 lines of the data, and pass that to `./lossopt` through a pipe?  If so what I did can be used pretty easily.  Just in the for loop do `lossopt; cat $file` and have your function just print to stdout instead of writing a file.  Of course, you may not want/need all the temp files my approach creates, though you could delete `$file` in each iteration too

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a `read` loop and redirection:

```
#!/bin/bash

fnbase=${1:-file}
increment=${2:-100}

declare -i count=0
declare -i fcount=1

fname="$(printf "%s_%08d" "$fnbase" $((fcount)))"

while read -r line; do
    ((count == 0)) && :> "$fname"
    ((count++))
    echo "$line" >> "$fname"
    ((count % increment == 0)) && {
        count=0
        ((fcount++))
        fname="$(printf "%s_%08d" "$fnbase" $((fcount)))"
    }
done

exit 0
```

**use/output**

```
$ bash script.sh yourprefix <yourfile
```

Which will take `yourfile` with many thousands of lines and write every 100 lines out to `yourprefix_00000001` -> `yourprefix_99999999` (default is `file_000000001`, etc..). Each new filename is truncated to `0` lines before writing begins.

Again you can specify on the command line the number of lines to write to each file. E.g.:

```
$ bash script.sh yourprefix 20 <yourfile
```

Which will write 20 lines per file to `yourprefix_00000001` -> `yourprefix_99999999`

Comment: Oh, I read it completely opposite. I thought he wanted to take every 100th line from his mega-file and write that to a new file to then send to his program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though it may seem stupid for professional in bash, I will take the risk and post my own answer to my question

```
cat<<END>temp.par
Parameters for LOSSOPT
                  ***********************

START OF PARAMETERS:
lossin.out                            \Input file with distribution
1                                       \column number
lossopt.out                             \Output file
-3.0 3.0   0.01                      \xmin, xmax, xinc
-3.0 1
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
3.0 0.12

END
for i in {1..62500}
do
sed -n 1,100p ./rearnum.out >> ./lossin.out
echo temp.par | ./lossopt >> sdis.out
rm lossin.out
tail -n +101 rearnum.out > temp
tail -n +1 temp > rearnum.out
rm temp 
done
```

This script consequentially "eats" the big initial file and puts the "pieces" into the external program. After it takes one portion of 100 number, it deletes this portion from the big file. Then, the process repeats until the big file is empty. It is not an elegant solution but it worked for me.